# What is "sqrtPriceLimitX96" for in Uniswap?

Tags: solidity, uniswap, defi, uniswapv3

this code is from the [docs](https://docs.uniswap.org/protocol/guides/swaps/single-swaps):

```
ISwapRouter.ExactInputSingleParams memory params = ISwapRouter
        .ExactInputSingleParams({
            tokenIn: LINK,
            tokenOut: USDC,
            fee: poolFee,
            recipient: address(this),
            deadline: block.timestamp,
            amountIn: amountIn,
            amountOutMinimum: 0,                
            sqrtPriceLimitX96: 0
        });
```

I understand what each parameter means but `sqrtPriceLimitX96`. same docs say this:

> sqrtPriceLimitX96: We set this to zero - which makes this parameter
> inactive. In production, this value can be used to set the limit for
> the price the swap will push the pool to, which can help protect
> against price impact or for setting up logic in a variety of
> price-relevant mechanisms.

Can someone explain what this is for? Why is this inactive?

Answer (score 1):

sqrtPriceLimitX96 at production level it used to determine limits on the pool prices. which cannot be exceeded by the swap. and in test level you can set it to 0, than it's ignored.

Actually in real scenarios we need to set price limit for swap, because every swap has impact on price and this change in price will change your use case and effect so by sqrtPriceLimitX96, we can limit the swap

Comment: you mean the ratio? `sqrtPriceX96` represents the ratio between two tokens. so we are telling if, after swap, if price ratio exceeds the `sqrtPriceLimitX96` do not execute it. And in development price impact is not important. Am I correct?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the comment for sqrtPriceLimitX96 in uniswapV3-core

```
    // @param sqrtPriceLimitX96 The Q64.96 sqrt price limit. If zero for one, the price cannot be less than this
    /// value after the swap. If one for zero, the price cannot be greater than this value after the swap
```

when swap zero for one,

Price = Amount1/Amount0
Amount1 = Amount0 * Price

Only do this swap when the Price is not less than the limit（sqrtPriceX96) —— we'll get enough Asset1